# What OS do I install on parallels to run Quartus II and other design software?

Tags: quartus-ii, windows

NOTE: I see a few similar questions on here in regards to Quartus II but I have some additional questions I believe would be best delivered in a new thread.

I'm fixing to run windows 7 or 8 off parallels for my macbook pro v10.8. The whole reason is to accommodate software like mulitsim and Quartus II for school. I've installed parallels already but have not continued with installing any OS until I get some advice. I have three questions that I would appreciate anyone's advice or opinion on.

1.)

I was wondering if Quartus II is compatible with windows 8. I'm sure it is since it's just an updated OS from windows 7 but I wanted to make sure I wouldn't run into any problems. I'm attaching a link below that gives the system requirements for Quartus II. A few things throw me off because it shows it's compatible with 7 but can't find anything about 8.

http://www.altera.com/download/os-support/oss-index.html

2.)

What version should I install 7 or 8? I only ask because I've heard negative feedback on the interface/environment of Windows 8. I shouldn't be needing much functionality with it other than hoping on Quartus II, mulitsim or other related software for class projects and labs.

3.)

From my understanding ubuntu is a Linux derived OS. I like the interface/overlay of ubuntu and would prefer it above windows. However, can I run Quartus II of it? Again the link I posted above shows some Linux compatibility but can't find anything about ubuntu. If so would this be a better option or would I get more compatibility with windows 7 or 8 for circuit/design specific software?

Answer (score 1):

1) It will probably work on windows 8 just fine.  It's more likely that you would have issues with device drivers for programming cables and the like than with regular software.

2) Just install windows 7.  The windows 8 interface is rather whacky and it may be cumbersome to navigate the 'edges and corners' tablet paradigm when the OS is running in a window.

3) I have no problems running Altera Quartus II and Xilinx ISE under Arch Linux; you should have little trouble with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1+2) If you're familiar with Windows 7 but not 8, then stay with 7. There aren't enough benefits yet with regards to running 8.

3) The gratis Linux distro closest to RHEL is [CentOS](http://centos.org/). It should provide the least friction with regards to running the various bits of Linux software. Keep in mind notes 2, 4, and 5 from the linked page though.